# How do I annotate an `attrs` validator function without breaking it?

Tags: python, mypy, python-attrs

Using the attrs library, I can define a validator for attribute values:

```
from attrs import define, field

def is_odd(inst, attr, value):
    if value % 2 == 1:
        return None

    raise ValueError("Only odd values allowed")

@define
class Foo:
  bar = field(validator=is_odd)

Foo(1)
Foo(2)
```

The `Foo(1)` instantiation succeeds and the `Foo(2)` instantiation fails with a `ValueError`, as intended.

Unsurprisingly, this code does not type-check (according to `mypy --strict`):

```
foo.py:3:1: error: Function is missing a type annotation  [no-untyped-def]
    def is_odd(inst, attr, value):
    ^
foo.py:11:3: error: Need type annotation for "bar"  [var-annotated]
      bar = field(validator=is_odd)
      ^
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, I don't see how to annotate it so that it does.  A naive first attempt might look like:

```
from attrs import Attribute, define, field

def is_odd(inst: object, attr: Attribute, value: int) -> None:
    if value % 2 == 1:
        return None

    raise ValueError("Only odd values allowed")

@define
class Foo:
  bar: int = field(validator=is_odd)

Foo(1)
Foo(2)
```

However `mypy --strict` reports this error:

```
foo.py:3:32: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Attribute"  [type-arg]
```

This can be fixed by supplying the missing type parameter:

```
from attrs import Attribute, define, field

def is_odd(inst: object, attr: Attribute[int], value: int) -> None:
    if value % 2 == 1:
        return None

    raise ValueError("Only odd values allowed")

@define
class Foo:
  bar: int = field(validator=is_odd)

Foo(1)
Foo(2)
```

This satisfies mypy:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

However, the program is now broken at runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    def is_odd(inst: object, attr: Attribute[int], value: int) -> None:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How can the program be made correct at runtime and also type-check under `mypy --strict` (without just adding "ignore" comments to silence the error)?

Comment: Seems like removing `[int]` after `Attribute` would fix the error

Comment: That gives the 2nd version of the example which works at runtime and fails type checking.

Comment: There is a related issue in the attrs github -> https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/524

Comment: If you are not using the `attr` argument you could safely annotate it with `Any`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/524) Github issue, quote the type annotation:

```py
from attrs import Attribute, define, field


def is_odd(inst: object, attr: "Attribute[int]", value: int) -> None:
    if value % 2 == 1:
        return None

    raise ValueError("Only odd values allowed")


@define
class Foo:
    bar: int = field(validator=is_odd)


Foo(1)
Foo(2)
```

or use `from __future__ import annotations`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from attrs import Attribute, define, field


def is_odd(inst: object, attr: Attribute[int], value: int) -> None:
    if value % 2 == 1:
        return None

    raise ValueError("Only odd values allowed")


@define
class Foo:
    bar: int = field(validator=is_odd)


Foo(1)
Foo(2)
```